# Remove space below numbers/bullets in itemize/enumerate environments

Tags: spacing, enumerate, itemize

I am using `itemize` and `enumerate` environments and while I have removed the indentation using the `enumitem` package I also want to remove the space below the numbers/bullets.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.3in, bottom=1.2in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in]{geometry}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\everymath{\displaystyle}

\newcommand{\3}{\vspace{0.3cm}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

This is what I have so far:
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
\item \lipsum[1]
\item \lipsum[1]
\end{enumerate}

What I want from the itemize/enumerate environments is something like that (without the spaces bellow the numbers/bullets):

\3

(1) \lipsum[1]

\3

(2) \lipsum[1]


\end{document}
```

This is what I have:

[image]

Something like that is what I want:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It suffices to use the `wide` option  of enumitem. The left matgin is set to 0. Note that you still can have the first line of the item indented if you wish, writing `wide=some value`. I give an example of both:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[top=0.3in, bottom=1.2in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in]{geometry}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

What I want from the itemize/enumerate environments is something like that (without the spaces bellow the numbers or bullets):
\begin{enumerate}[wide]
\item \lipsum[1]
\item \lipsum[1]
\end{enumerate}

Or if you want to have an indented label:
\setlength\parindent{1em}

\begin{enumerate}[wide=\parindent]
\item \lipsum[1]
\item \lipsum[1]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]